# Hiding a banner on Purchase?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I am struggling to hide a banner view when a purchase is made.

I have 2 separate versions, one is an Admob banner (bannerView_), the other is actually a view which I called _adView they share the same place but rotate around depending on what is viewing.

Anyhow, the Admob banner hides no problem, but the _adView does not, here is hiding code;

```
-(void)removeBanner:(NSNotification *) notify {
    NSLog(@"Removing:");
    if ([MKStoreManager isFeaturePurchased:@"com.fredsworld.ubercool.removeads"]) {
        [bannerView_ setHidden:YES];
        [_adView setHidden:YES];

        NSLog(@"Removed:");
    }
}
```

Basically that runs on a purchase, so it updates the screen instantly,

The _adView code to call it in the viewDidLoad is;

```
  CGFloat y = self.view.frame.size.height - 50.0;
        TapForTapAdView *adView = [[TapForTapAdView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, y, 320, 50) delegate: self];
        [self.view addSubview: adView];
```

I have synthesized adView and created it as an object, but still no joy, it does not disappear when the purchase is made.

Although, it DOES work, as if you close the app, then re open, it has gone but obviously I want it to disappear immediately upon purchase.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'll need to call the `setHidden:` methods right away when the purchase is made.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean? As I am already doing that I believe as it works for the other bannerView?

Comment: what if you call removeBanner from viewWillAppear?

Answer (score 0):

it was solved by removing the TapForTapAdView *adView on line 2 and simply changing to self.adView =